Retrieve related data from another services
In context of microservices, I have a product service and an image service. Each product will have list of image id. When call request for a product list, what is the best way I can get images’ url from image service? Right now, I’m thinking about gRPC, is it good?

Are you asking about network protocol / mechanism for communication between your microservices (gRPC, HTTP, etc.), or about making a design choice on where exactly to implement that request of images? If for the first, it does not make much difference until you have specific requirements for your project

Sorry for confusion, I’m asking about making a design choice

fyi this is off-topic, as it's an open-ended opinion/discussion/recommendation question, with no single"right" answer. Please read [ask], and then consider posting a detailed question with code, sample data, expected vs actual behavior, errors, etc (a [mcve])
